# How to loose 45kg at old age having arthritis

Tags: weight-loss

I know someone who is in her old age, but has low mobility due to arthritis. However, she is extremely overweight and would be best to loose around 45kg (eventually I mean).

But considering the age and arthritis, what non-surgical options are there (if any)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Diet will shed more pounds than any exercise. That said, people should approach diets the same way they do a new exercise regimen: By making small, digestible changes that are safe and sustainable for the rest of one’s life. Crash dieting is not sustainable and is unsafe.

Something such as water aerobics or water jogging might help her body to spark some better metabolic functioning as well.

Small goals: 1 pound a week is an awesome goal to shoot for!

Comment: Digestible, I get it.